# Kohana 3 jQuery/AJAX request not working

Tags: php, ajax, frameworks, routes, kohana

I am trying to post some data to a controller in Kohana 3 using the jQuery AJAX method.  I seem to have an issue with the data not getting to where I want it to be.  I want the data to go to the /application/classes/controller/stock.php file where the file will process the data.  I can't seem to figure this one out.  Hopefully someone can help.  My jQuery ajax call is:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add_stock',
            data: { 'links': 'link_array' }
            });
```

'add_stock' is the name of the action within the controller.  I didn't know what else to try.  I've also tried '.' and './' hoping that would be right but it's not.  In Firebug, although it says the request was 200 OK, I see that the "RESPONSE" is **"Failed to load source for: http://localhost/ddm/v2/stocks/add_stock"** and my script in my controller which grabs the data isn't working.  Here is that code in case it helps:

```
$links = $_POST['links'];

$link_obj = Jelly::factory('link')
    ->set('stock', $stock->id)
    ->set('links', $links);

    $link_obj->save();
```

I think that the problem is that I'm giving the ajax call the ROUTE and not the actual page it needs to deliver the POST data to.  I just can't figure it out here.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

rename your controller method "add_stock" to "add_stock_action"

you can also see what exactly went wrong if you klick the link where firebug tells you 200.